# Compare AD group members with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to compare two AD groups (Over 5000 users) and find matching users in it. After that I want to locate those users and remove them from one of the AD groups.

I get exceeded over 5000 and it errors out.

```
Compare-Object (Get-ADGroupMember "Imprivata1") (Get-ADGroupMember "Imprivata2") -Property "Name" -IncludeEqual | Sort-Object Name | Export-Csv "C:\users\$env:username\Desktop\compareadgroups3.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What's the error ? is it "invalid enumeration context" ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the error message in full there. Also  remove the tags of Powershell versions you are not actually using

Comment: This is the error message: The size limit for this request was exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the maximum number of group members `Get-ADGroupMember` can retrieve is 5000. If there are more members in the group, you will see error

> Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded

You can overcome that by using `Get-ADGroup` and expand the `.Member` property.

```
$members1 = (Get-ADGroup 'Imprivata1' -Properties Member).Member
$members2 = (Get-ADGroup 'Imprivata2' -Properties Member).Member
```

This will give you arrays of `DistinguishedName` items, which will serve perfectly to uniquely identify the users, way better than you could using the `.Name` property. (The DistinguishedName is unique within the same domain, the Name property is not)

Remember that both `Get-ADGroupMember` and the `.Member` property from the code above can return objects of type user, group and computer.

Comment: Compare-Object $members1 = (Get-ADGroup 'Imprivata1' -Properties Member).Member) $members2 = (Get-ADGroup 'Imprivata2' -Properties Member).Member) -Property "Name" -IncludeEqual | Sort-Object members | Export-Csv "C:\users\$env:username\Desktop\compareadgroups.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation                                                                                                                        This isn't working.

Comment: Don't try and put it all in one single line. Create the two variables with members like I did. Then compare `Compare-Object $members1 $members2 -IncludeEqual`

Comment: $members1 = (Get-ADGroup 'Imprivata1' -Properties Member).Member
$members2 = (Get-ADGroup 'Imprivata2' -Properties Member).Member


Compare-Object (Get-ADGroupMember "$members1") (Get-ADGroupMember "$members2") -Property "Member" -IncludeEqual | Sort-Object Member | Export-Csv "C:\users\$env:username\Desktop\compareadgroups2.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation 

Like this?

Comment: No, just `Compare-Object $members1 $members2 -IncludeEqual`. These variables already have all the info. You don't use `Get-ADGroupMember` at all

Comment: Is there a way to not have to filter the users that are in both AD groups?